# direct access denied on subdomain's subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

my directory:

```
domain.com/
-----------subdomain/
---------------------subdirectory/
```

I've created subdomain as `subdomain.domain.com`
I need to access `subdomain.domain.com/subdirectory` but is shows: 404
I can access `domain.com/subdomain/subdirectory/`

please tell me how to do that.

### EDITED ###########

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+^)$ download/content/$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
   php_value post_max_size 200M
</IfModule>
```

if I add the following before my rule, it stops my existing. and if I add it after my rule. it doesn't execute because of [L] flag

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wap\.
RewriteRule !^wap/ wap%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: What is `DocumentRoot` of `subdomain`?

Comment: root is domain.com. I've created subdomain and it creates a folder named "subdomain" under the domain.com.

Comment: Can you create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://subdomain.domain.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value.

Comment: it shows, doc_root => no value

Comment: Can you copy/paste full output of `phpinfo` into a pastebin and give me its link.

Comment: http://www.theqsoft.com/phpinfo%28%29.htm

Comment: ok DOCUMENT_ROOT is `/home/admin/public_html/` instead of `/home/admin/public_html/subdomain` change your VirtualHost config to make it `/home/admin/public_html/subdomain`

Comment: I don't have access to server configuration... is that possible with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Have this rule in your root htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wap\.
RewriteRule !^wap/ wap%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ download/content/$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
   php_value post_max_size 200M
</IfModule>
```

Comment: My .htaccess is RewriteEngine on                                    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                                
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                                
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA]                              
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+^)$ download/content/$1 [L]                    

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
   php_value post_max_size 200M
</IfModule>

Comment: You need to place this before your existing rules.

Comment: I tried, but anything before my rule conflicts. as the flag is [L] it stops all other rules. I am confused...

Comment: post your complete .htaccess in your question

Comment: I've added the htaccess file on my question

Comment: Ok and what is your subdomain name? Is `/wap/` an existing directory that has all the files for wap subdomain?

Comment: subdomain is wap. and yes it contains all files for wap sub directory.

Comment: ok try updated code. (Make sure above rule in `/home/admin/public_html/.htaccess`

Comment: no. it doesn't work. still when I hit wap.mydomain.com it redirect to mydomain.com/wap

Comment: There is no redirect rule in above .htaccess. That means you have some rule somewhere else not shown here.

Comment: I don't know. I see nothing here... may be I should buy a new domain for wap. I don't think subdomain will work...

Comment: It should work if config/rules are setup correctly by your server admin.

Comment: My project is developed in codeigniter, I am checking their solution...if it helps...